# Invalid Method identifier specified error while put_integration method is called

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to create a resource and it's integration in aws apigateway using python. I am using boto3 package. This is the code i have tried

```
import boto3
import config

session = boto3.session.Session(config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, config.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
client = session.client('apigateway', region_name=config.AWS_REGION)
api_endpoint = input("\n\tEnter the API endpoint: \n")

response = client.create_resource(
    restApiId=config.REST_API_ID,
    parentId=config.PARENT_RESOURCE,
    pathPart=api_endpoint
)
resource_id = response["id"]
response2 = client.put_integration(
        restApiId=config.REST_API_ID,
        resourceId=resource_id,
        httpMethod='ANY',
        type='HTTP_PROXY',
        uri=url,
        integrationHttpMethod="ANY",
        connectionType='VPC_LINK',
    )
```

But i always get **botocore.errorfactory.NotFoundException: An error occurred (NotFoundException) when calling the PutIntegration operation: Invalid Method identifier specified**

I have tried http methods GET, POST, PUT. Resource is created successfully.put_integration method is not working properly

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem.

I fixed it by using put_method(httpMethod='ANY') to create'ANY' method in same resource before calling put_integration(httpMethod='ANY').

If the resource doesn't exist corresponding method when you calling put_integration(), it will raise that error.